# My Pentadoku puzzles (Jigsaw Sudoku)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

In each of the following puzzles, fill the empty squares with numbers so that every row, column and irregularly shaped region contains the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 exactly once.

[image: Jigsaw Sudoku 1]

[image: Jigsaw Sudoku 2]

[image: Jigsaw Sudoku 3]

[image: Jigsaw Sudoku 4]

[image: Jigsaw Sudoku 5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the completed grids...

#1:

> [image: 1]

#2:

> [image: 2]

#3:

> [image: 3]

#4:

> [image: 4]

#5:

> [image: 5]