# 5×5 sudoku with special properties

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

Complete the network with numbers from 1 to 5 so that the same number does not occur in any line, column, specially marked figure and on both diagonals.

[image]

I tried to start with a number that I know for sure goes to that place, but I couldn't find one. The only thing I've tried is guessing the numbers on the diagonal, but there's probably a much better solution that I'm still not seeing.

*Source: School Sudoku competition for children from 1st to 4th grade of primary school in Croatia*

Comment: For similar puzzles, please visit:  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117064/my-pentadoku-puzzles-jigsaw-sudoku

Comment: The funny thing is that if you completely ignore the regions, there are sill only 2 solutions.  If you ignore the digits, all solutions are permutations of the 2 solutions, i.e. solutions where digits are replaced by others.

Comment: Need the full rules. I presume it is that each row, column, and region must be 1 to 5. But do the marked diagonals also need to be 1 to 5?

Comment: I make videos on Math puzzles and post them on YouTube . I want to make a video on this puzzle . Is this an open source puzzle or would I need permission from School sudoku competition to make a video on this that goes on YouTube ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remember that each shape has 5 squares, so must contain all values 1 to 5 exactly once.

There is only one place where you can

> put a 5 in the figure in the middle left. The 5 cannot go in R3C2 or R4C3 so must go in the only other empty spot of this figure, R3C1.

Simmilarly,

> The figure at the top right has only one place where its 3 can go.

Comment: Also R4C3 having to be a 1(naked single)

Comment: Why does a partial solution get chosen as the answer?

Comment: @BillOnne If you read the question, it appears OP was not posting this as a "contest" puzzle, but genuinely wanted help solving.

Answer (score 1):

As [Jaap](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/118370) stated,

> the middle-left region's 5 must be R3C1

and

> the top right region's 3 must be R2C5

This allows us to complete row 2 as

> 42513.

the middle-left region as

> R4C3=1, so R3C2=4

so row 3 must be

> 54321

so row 4 must be

> 35142

so column 2 must be

> 32451 as otherwise the bottom left region has two 3s

and column 3 must be

> 25314 as otherwise the top left region has two 4s

and column 4 must be

> 51243 as otherwise the top left region has two 3s

after which the remaining cells can be determined as each region must have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 once each.

We don't need the diagonal constraint. Without it, we can determine row 3 and R4C3. The top right region's

> 3 must be in C5, so R4C5 is not 3 but 2, so row 4 is 35142.

This determines column 2 as above, locating the final

> 1 at R1C1. So R2C1 is not 2 but 4, so column 1 is 14532, so R5C3 is 4 to complete the bottom left region.

This determines column 3; this time the reason is that

> 52314 would give row 2 two 2s.

And the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Took me less than 5 minutes using pen and paper.

> 13254
>  42513
>  54321
>  35142
>  21435

(Sorry, I don’t know how to make it look like a graph)

Comment: Why does a full answer get down-voted without comment?

Comment: @BillOnne Possibly because the answerer showed no working, so the answer gives no clue as to how one was supposed to find it.

Comment: @RosieF: Thank you for the feedback. I’ll keep that in mind for my future answers! :)